# How can I get an attribute property in the filter template (or any other template)?

Tags: attributes, layered-navigation

How can I get the `is_filterable` attribute property in the filter template (`template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml`). Preferably without loading the attribute again.

`$this->getisFilterable()` is not working.

```
    mysql> select * from catalog_eav_attribute where attribute_id=92\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                 attribute_id: 92
      frontend_input_renderer: NULL
                    is_global: 1
                   is_visible: 1
                is_searchable: 1
                is_filterable: 2
                is_comparable: 1
          is_visible_on_front: 0
     is_html_allowed_on_front: 0
      is_used_for_price_rules: 0
      is_filterable_in_search: 0
      used_in_product_listing: 0
             used_for_sort_by: 0
              is_configurable: 1
                     apply_to: simple
is_visible_in_advanced_search: 1
                     position: 0
           is_wysiwyg_enabled: 0
      is_used_for_promo_rules: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml, you can  attribute data by using below `getAttributeModel():`

> ```
>  $AttributeModel = $this->getAttributeModel();
>  echo '<pre>';
>  print_r($AttributeModel->getData());
> ```